# Trigonometric Applications in 3D

Tags: trigonometry

A square‐based tent has the cross‐sectional shape shown.

[image: A squared-based tent]

The side wall goes up at an angle of elevation of $60^\circ$ for $2$m, then continues at an angle of elevation of $30^\circ$ for another $2$m to the peak. Determine an exact value for the height of the tent.

Comment: What have you done so far? Please update the body of the question with your attempts.

Comment: This is not a 3D problem.

Comment: What have you tried? We are not here to blindly answer homework questions - people will be more willing to help you if they can see that you have put in some effort yourself

Comment: Using Special Triangles, I found the height of the top triangle and 1m and base as √3m. The answer is √3 +1 m but I don't know how to proceed to find the bottom trapezoid's height.

Comment: @LogixG Move the line drawn on the diagram to the left until it touches the point at which the elevation changes and then you have a second right triangle you can evaluate

Comment: If I use the cosine law to find the slant height of the isosceles triangle with the lengths of the two sides as 2m and the enclosed angle 150° then the slant height is 4√3 +8m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First consider the top triangle

```
    /|     
  2/ |x       
  /  |        
30----
```

We can find $x$ using trigonometry

\begin{align}\sin(30)&=\frac x2\\
x&=2\sin(30)\\
&=1\end{align}

Now consider the bottom shape - we want to find $y$

```
     -------
    /   |    \
  2/    |y    \
  /     |      \
60--------------
```

We can think about moving the centre line to the left until it touches the top left corner of the shape

```
     -------
    /|       \
  2/ |y       \
  /  |         \
60--------------
```

Now we have another right triangle which we can evaluate:

\begin{align}\sin(60)&=\frac{y}{2}\\
y&=2\sin(60)\\
&=\sqrt 3\end{align}

Now the total height of the shape is \begin{align}x+y&=1+\sqrt 3\end{align}

Comment: Oh that's what you meant by moving the line. Great! Thanks a lot.

Comment: In problems like this, it is always useful to see if you can create easier shapes by moving lines around